# Is disposing a local brush variable necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

MSDN recommends disposing any variable of type System.Drawing.Brush before its last reference is released. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Brush object's Finalize method.

As we know, local variables are destroyed automatically when the control flow goes out of the scope of the method it belongs. So, is it necessary to dispose a brush object every time if it is local?

Comment: yes, it's necessary. That's how the GC works.

Comment: `As we know, local variables are destroyed automatically when the control flow goes out of the scope` - that is a misconception. **Nothing** happens in C# as a direct consequence of your variable going out of scope. In C++ for example, the *destructor* would be called in this case, but in C#, only `IDisposable` in conjunction with the `using` statement can achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is necessary.  The flaw in your logic is when you said:

> As we know, local variables are destroyed automatically when the control flow goes out of the scope of the method it belongs.

That statement is false.

When variables go out of scope, that means that they are candidates to be destroyed by the garbage collector at some point in the future, but most likely not right away.  As such, if it is important to release system resources right away, you need to manually do so rather than waiting for the garbage collector to get around to doing it at some point in the future.

That is why classes which use system resources implement the `IDisposable` interface.  They expect you to call their `Dispose` method when you are done with them so that they can immediately release the system resource.  It's safe to assume that you should always call the `Dispose` method on every object that implements the `IDisposable` interface.  If it wasn't necessary, they wouldn't implement that interface.

In the case case of the `Brush` class, it creates a system object via the GDI API.  In order to draw filled figures via the GDI API, you must call a method to create a brush object.  The API returns a handle to the brush object which you can then use to refer to that brush in later API calls.  When you are done with the brush, you are supposed to call a `DeleteObject` API call in order to delete the object.  Since each process in Windows is limited to a maximum of 10,000 GDI objects, it's very important that you delete them when you are done with them, otherwise you will run out of GDI objects and cause an `OutOfMemoryException`.  That is why the `Brush` class implements the `IDisposable` interface--so that it can delete the underlying GDI object.

It's recommended when possible, to use a `using` block on all disposable objects.  When execution leaves the `using` block, it will automatically call the `Dispose` method on the object for you, even if execution leaves the block due to an exception.

```
using(Brush b = New Brush())
{
    // use the brush
}
```

Or

```
Using b As New Brush()
    ' use the brush
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

> As we know, local variables are destroyed automatically

No, that's a myth.  The word "destroy" is entirely inappropriate, that suggests that the program actually makes an effort to do something special with the variable in order to invoke destruction.  Like throwing a brick into a glass window.  That's just not how it works, the variable simply disappears in thin air.  It is forgotten, as though it never existed.  No brick is thrown.  Ultimately the storage for the variable is overwritten by something else, it is *reused*.  Usually in a fraction of a microsecond.

Not having to destroy a variable is what makes managed code competitive with native code.  A C++ compiler for example must do it explicitly, the RAII pattern is boilerplate.  Older runtime implementations that use reference counting are another example, they must ensure to explicitly count-down the reference count.  That's extra code that managed code doesn't need, the garbage collector knows when a local variable is in use.  It is just a bit slow at getting that job done, the reason that IDisposable exists.  An attempt to add reference counting to the CLR was an [abysmal failure](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/refcount_rotor.doc&ei=o1Z-UqbgHeGsyAGZ34GgBA&usg=AFQjCNFKNaOFNNX9lzYQ6uTonFrUg2JHyQ&sig2=BxrJK7c7mkEo45ZYwAmFaA&bvm=bv.56146854,d.aWc), it could not compete with the GC.

Using the *using* statement is required to throw the brick.

Comment: "Ultimately the storage for the variable is overwritten by something else, it is reused. Usually in a fraction of a microsecond." This is a very inaccurate way to describe GC. It's not simply written over in a microsecond, it's kept around until GC happens and the finalizer is called, only then is the memory released for another object to overwrite.

Comment: Another frequent misconception.  The GC heap stores objects, variables only store a reference to it.  Just a pointer.

Comment: Ok, but then it's only the reference to it that is destroyed quickly. The object on the heap, which is actually the important part, is still there until GC gets around to cleaning it up.

Comment: There's the word "destroyed" again.  Nothing is destroyed, there is no brick.  The core ability to store a variable in a CPU register and have it just overwritten by another variable value is absolutely essential to speed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the local variable is destroyed, that is just a reference to the Brush object which is locate don the managed heap. It's not until the garbage collector sweeps the managed heap that the actual object is destroyed and the resources freed.

As a general rule: Always call `Dispose` on any object implementing `IDisposable` when you're done with the object.

The best way is often to use the `using` construct which will dispose correctly even in the case of exceptions:

```
using(var brush = CreateBrush())
{
   brush.PaintSomethingNice();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary. In general, if it implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should dispose it when you're done with it. When it goes out of scope, that only means that it is eligible for garbage collection. GC might not dispose of it for a long time, so you should dispose of it immediately.